# Return an arrayList as message in custom exception in JAVA

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

I need to output a `List<String>` when an exception is thrown. I want the program to stop its execution once the exception is thrown.
To make things clear, my code has these two functions:

```
       List<String> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public Boolean validation(Obj obj){
           if(condition1){ exceptions.add("exception1");}
           if(condition2){ exceptions.add("exception2");}
              .
              .
              .
           if(exceptions.size() > 0) return false;
           else return true;
        }
    
        public Obj getValidResponse(Obj obj){
           if(validation(obj)){ return obj;}
           else{ throw new CustomException(exceptions);}  //on this line, the program should return the List<String> of all the exceptions stored. 
        }
```

Whenever I throw the exception, the list is printed following the technical exception message which I do not want.
Also, I cannot figure out a way to return using a `getMessage()` function implemented in my customException, in the throw statement as it gives a `Expected throwable type` error.

My Custom exception class looks like :

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException{
    public CustomException(List<String> s) {
        super(String.valueOf(s));
    }
}
```

I am pretty new to this, any kind of help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understood it properly or not but it seems like you want to show multiple error messages to user when exception is thrown i.e. list of all possible failed validation messages. If that is the case, you can create a custom object that your exception returns when an exception is thrown. And in that object, you can have a list of error messages.

Comment: Yes. what i want exactly is; whenever the function 'validation' return false, it should throw an exception which would look like ["exception1", "exception3", "exceptionX"...]. and the program would terminate. About your suggestion, how am i supposed to make create a custom object? can you please elaborate on that? thanks

Comment: An exception class must extend a Throwable, usually Exception or RuntimeException, which seems your CustomException class is not. Please, update you question with the code for the CustomException class.

Comment: Hi @whbogado, i have added my CustomException. The issue with this is, i still get result like -- Exception in thread "main" CustomException: ["exception1", "exception2", ....] . is there a way to avoid this and just return the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sub classing from RuntimeException (use a proper name and fields for the exception to make is self descriptive):

```java
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private List<String> myStrings;

    public CustomException(List<String> s) {
        this.myString = s;
    }

    public List<String> getMyStrings() {
        return myStrings;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return String.join(",", myStrings);
    }
}
```

Java can only throw `Throwables`, no other objects. This is different from other programming languages. And the `getMessage` method which is used for a string representation is always returning a `String`. When you need a different behavior returning the real list you have to use you own interceptor
/ fault barrier reading the list of strings directly and apply a  proper handling.

Can you be more precise when you need the list of string as `List<String>`. It seems you are using some handler code not only interested in the string message of the exception. In your code it seems that you are trying to return an `Obj`. Is your idea here to return an error list instead if it fails? This does not work that way. If you throw something then this will raise an exception and nothing is returned. This is a different program flow. If you want to return the list of errors you could also create a special

```java
public class StatusResult {

    private boolean error;
    
    private Obj sucessObj;
   
    private List<String> errorMsgs;

// add constructor and getters here ...
}
```

But this kind of success / error handling is not Java like.

Comment: thanks @k_o_ , but how am I supposed to use the `getMyStrings()` function in the `throw` statement? If I use just `throw new CustomException(exceptions)`, it return something like this - `Exception in thread "main" CustomException:["exc1", "exc4"]` -- which Is what I do not want.

Comment: `Exception in thread ...` sounds like an automatic stack trace message created by Java. I was assuming you are catching the exceptions somewhere and handle it to call `getMyStrings`. When printing the stack trace or passing the exception to a logger Java is using the `getMessage` method. The constructor I have used is just joining the passed list, this is what is used by `getMessage`. You can also directly overriding `getMessage` to have a better format. In Java only Throwables can be thrown, this is different in other programming languages.

Comment: See my updated answer. I guess your goal is not yet clear.

Answer (score -1):

Well here is one solution for such custom exception class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception{

    private final List<String> errors;

    public CustomException(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {

        String msg = errors.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));

        return msg;
    }

}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        errorFunc();
    } catch (CustomException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void errorFunc() throws  CustomException {

    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    errors.add("error#1");
    errors.add("error#2");
    errors.add("error#3");

    throw new CustomException(errors);
}
```

Output:

```
[error#1, error#2, error#3]
```

But please note that this is not good practice in general. An exception should represent one error and not multiple ones. Normally you would create a base class, which represents a special "category" of your exceptions. Then specific errors can have their own exception that is derived from that base exception. One example is the FileNotFoundExcpetion (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), which is derived from IOException (which in turn is derived from the Exception class).

Throwing a string of multiple errors might indicate that your function is doing more than one thing (and these things might go wrong).

Comment: I don't really understand why this answer was downvoted, it produces the right output. Yes, it does use a checked exception, which can be criticized, however using an unchecked exception won't work better because of how Java outputs exceptions. In each case, you will have to use a try/catch block and see: [Unchecked Exceptions - The Controversy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class CustomException extends Exception{
    private List<String> exceptions;
    public CustomException(List<String> exp) {
        this.exceptions = exp;
    }   
    public List<String> getExceptions(){
        return exceptions;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        try {
            boolean result = getValidResponse();
        }catch(CustomException e) {
            List<String> msgs = e.getExceptions();
            for(String ss:msgs) {
                System.out.println(ss);
            }
        }
    }   
    static List<String> exps = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public static boolean validation(boolean error){
        boolean result = false;
        if(error) {         
            exps.add("Error msg 1");
            exps.add("Error msg 2");            
        }else{
            result =  true;
        }        
        return result;
    }   
    public static boolean getValidResponse() throws CustomException{
        boolean r = false;
        validation(true);
        if(exps.size()>0) {
            throw new CustomException(exps);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```